# SQL - Converting number to decimals resulting to 0 (avoid automatically rounds)

Tags: sql, decimal, numeric

When executing the below query, I am getting 0.0000010

The data column values have a data type of being numeric values (19,4)

```
select convert (decimal(19,7),
  partlen*parthgt*partlen/1728) as result 
from tab1 where part ='847S'
```

However for there are instances when I need to divide by 1828 instead of 1728 where the result happen to be smaller. In the below example, I am getting 0.0000000

select convert (decimal(19,7),partlen*parthgt*partlen/1828) as result from tab1 where part ='847S'

I am on MS SQL Studio 2016.

Comment: How large are the actual values that you're multiplying?

Answer (score 1):

You're bumping into the rules detailed here: [Precision, Scale, and Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)

The precision (scale) of a multiplication is generally the sum of the precision (scale) of the two factors, until you reach the limit of 38 when it starts stealing places from the decimal side.

You'll need to cast the intermediate values/expressions to a lower precision so you can keep more digits to the right of the decimal.

This should help you get a better idea how it works:

```
declare @x decimal(19, 4) = 1, @y decimal(19, 4) = 1, @z decimal(19, 4) = 1;

select 'Product of two decimal(19, 4)' as [Type],
    sql_variant_property(@x * @y, 'precision'),
    sql_variant_property(@x * @y, 'scale')
union all
select 'Product of three decimal(19, 4)',
    sql_variant_property(@x * @y * @z, 'precision'),
    sql_variant_property(@x * @y * @z, 'scale')
union all
select 'Product followed by division',
    sql_variant_property(@x * @y * @z / 1728, 'precision'),
    sql_variant_property(@x * @y * @z / 1728, 'scale')
union all
select 'Intermediate cast',
    sql_variant_property(cast(@x * @y * @z as decimal(19, 12)) / 1728, 'precision'),
    sql_variant_property(cast(@x * @y * @z as decimal(19, 12)) / 1728, 'scale')
```

Results:

```
       Type                    Precision    Scale
Product of two decimal(19, 4)     38          7
Product of three decimal(19, 4)   38          6
Product of three then division    38          6
Intermediate numerator cast       24         17
```

The ultimate fix for your problem is probably to reduce precision before starting any calculations. Will you actually be dealing with values as big as a quadrillion?

Comment: Thanks, mostly just up to billion